# Allowing only numbers and one decimal

Tags: javascript

Guys and gals i have this piece of JavaScript code that only allows for numbers and one decimal period.  The problem i'm having is that when i tab over to my textbox controls it highlights the value but i have press backspace to erase then enter a number. That is an extra keystroke that i want to prevent.

Props to the guy who created it found (http://www.coderanch.com/t/114528/HTML-CSS-JavaScript/decimal-point-restriction) and here is the code.  I put this on keyUp event.

```
 <script>
  // Retrieve last key pressed.  Works in IE and Netscape.
  // Returns the numeric key code for the key pressed.
  function getKey(e)
  {
    if (window.event)
       return window.event.keyCode;
    else if (e)
       return e.which;
    else
       return null;
  }
  function restrictChars(e, obj)
  {
    var CHAR_AFTER_DP = 2;  // number of decimal places
    var validList = "0123456789.";  // allowed characters in field
    var key, keyChar;
    key = getKey(e);
    if (key == null) return true;
    // control keys
    // null, backspace, tab, carriage return, escape
    if ( key==0 || key==8 || key==9 || key==13 || key==27 )
       return true;
    // get character
    keyChar = String.fromCharCode(key);
    // check valid characters
    if (validList.indexOf(keyChar) != -1)
    {
      // check for existing decimal point
      var dp = 0;
      if( (dp = obj.value.indexOf( ".")) > -1)
      {
        if( keyChar == ".")
          return false;  // only one allowed
        else
        {
          // room for more after decimal point?
          if( obj.value.length - dp <= CHAR_AFTER_DP)
            return true;
        }
      }
      else return true;
    }
    // not a valid character
    return false;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I suggest not doing this: capturing key events and preventing some of them. You will have to handle all control keys and it's a nightmare. Use a well-know library or let the event happen and then remove invalid characters (probably using regular expressions).

Comment: So you mean it would be better to validate when the control loses focus?

Comment: I'll put an answer of something I've done in past and worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can't use an already stable and well-know library, you can try something like this:

```
document.write('<input id="inputField" onkeyup="run(this)" />');

function run(field) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var regex = /\d*\.?\d?/g;
        field.value = regex.exec(field.value);
    }, 0);
}
```

I know it doesn't prevent the wrong char to appear, but it works.

PS: that `setTimeout(..., 0)` is a trick to execute the function after the value of the field has already been modified.

Comment: Alex, one last thing .. i the user clears and leaves the field how would i default it to 0?

Comment: @user2026047, create two more functions, one for `onblur` and other for `onfocus` that writes and clear the zero, respectively. But I suggest not doing it, wait for the validation phase (when you are retrieving the value of the fields to submit or something else) and if the field is clear "pretend that you retrieved zero".

Comment: This worked like a charm for me!  How would I be able to include 3 decimal places instead of 1?

Comment: Why was this ever accepted? It only allows one number after the decimal for some odd reason, how is that helpful ...

Answer (score 7):

```
<input type="text" class="decimal" value="" />
```

And in Js use this

```
$('.decimal').keyup(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(isNaN(val)){
         val = val.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
         if(val.split('.').length>2) 
             val =val.replace(/\.+$/,"");
    }
    $(this).val(val); 
});
```

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2YW8g/

THis worked for me, i have taken this answer from "Nickalchemist" and take none of its credit.

Comment: I tested a LOT of things, and this is the only one it worked. thanks! and thanks Nick, whoever you are :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sample solution that will accept a number with one(1) decimal point only. e.g 1.12, 11.5

```
Enter a number with one(1) decimal point only<br />
<input type="text" id="decimalPt"> <br />

$('.decimalPt').keypress(function(evt) {
  evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  if (charCode == 8 || charCode == 37) {
    return true;
  } else if (charCode == 46 && $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) {
    return false;
  } else if (charCode > 31 && charCode != 46 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
});
```

Take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/sudogem/h43r6g7v/12/

Comment: This works! Could you adapt it to allow a single minus as the first char too?

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be best to use something that already exists... like [Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('input').on('keydown', function (event) {
    return isNumber(event, this);
});
function isNumber(evt, element) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if ((charCode != 190 || $(element).val().indexOf('.') != -1)  // “.” CHECK DOT, AND ONLY ONE.
            && (charCode != 110 || $(element).val().indexOf('.') != -1)  // “.” CHECK DOT, AND ONLY ONE.
            && ((charCode < 48 && charCode != 8)
                    || (charCode > 57 && charCode < 96)
                    || charCode > 105))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to test on any browser. The accepted answer doesn't work on Firefox.

Try HTML5 type number:

```
<input type="number" placeholder="1.0" step="0.1">
```

You could define  `min="0" max="10"`

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#Controlling_input_size

**Note:** type="number" is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem with like this.

```
const sanitize = (value = '') => value.replace(/(-(?!\d))|[^0-9|-]/g, '') || ''

export const toNumeric = value => {
  let digits = sanitize(value)

  // parseInt with 0 fix/avoid NaN
  digits = parseInt(0 + digits)
  let newValue = digits.toString().padStart(4, 0)

  return newValue
}
```