# How can I control decimal field to allow enter more than one point?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a field that I can control that not accepts letters etc. I allow to enter "." In order to input decimals. How can I control that not more than one "."?

Here my source code:

```
$(".allow_decimal").on("input", function(evt) {
   var self = $(this);
   self.val(self.val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ''));
   if ((evt.which != 46 || self.val().indexOf('.') != -1) && 
       (evt.which < 48 || evt.which > 57)) 
   {
     evt.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

Comment: same question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/14610205/5208282

Comment: Yes but not have full correct answer -->  it doesn't prevent the wrong char to appear...

Comment: I used [THIS](https://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/ue8gj52t/) before, did the trick for me. It's not my work so I dunno what to do with it, maybe you update your question and credit the author yourself if it helped... ^^

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5 specification allows for a `number` input type. One of the attributes allowed for the `number` input is `step` which is the increments that the number may go up/down in:

```html
<form>
<input type="number" step="0.1" />
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

While, yes, you can type in something like '2.25', when you try to submit the form, any HTML5 compliant browser will tell you off for it:

[image: Screenshot]

This only applies to HTML5 compliant browsers: [CanIUse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number)

As always - don't trust anything sent by a user - ALWAYS validate on the server ;)

Comment: Yes thanks this is an option, but the tooltip that appear in our case that we're in spain mention de character of decimal to be "," and my program should be "." so i need to do it with code not with html

Comment: This is based on the locale of the computer being used. One suggestion is to add a `lang` attribute to the input field: `lang="en-150"`. Support for this is limited (I think it only works in Firefox?) but will show decimal instead of comma.