# Javascript regular expression fails in Firefox

Tags: javascript, regex

I wrote a function with the regular expression from the accepted answer to stackoverflow question [Allowing only numbers and one decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609521/allowing-only-numbers-and-one-decimal)

```js
function allowDecimal(field) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var regex = /\d*\.?\d?/g;
        field.value = regex.exec(field.value);
    }, 0);
}
```

```html
<br>For input say 2.5, chrome will give 2.5 while firefox will give 25<br>
<input type="number" onkeyup='allowDecimal(this);' id="baths"  name="baths">
```

It is supposed to accept only numbers, one decimal point and exactly one number after the decimal.
The expression is working fine in Chorome, but fails in firefox.
For input 2.5, in Chorome its shows 2.5 but in firefox it erases the dot and gives 25. 
What is wrong with the expression?

Comment: You should provide a *complete* [mcve] - Use the [live demo](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), include the `<input>`, show how you call the function.

Comment: I just guessed at what you were doing on the missing parts I mentioned above and built my own test case. I could not reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am just reading out your regex patter... "input can start with 0 **or** more numbers", "followed by an **optional** decimal point", "then finally followed by an **optional** single number" ...

Comment: `exec` returns an array .. is that really what you want!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be your use of `?` that is throwing this off.  Adding `?` makes the preceding characters (or set of characters) optional.  If you'd like to match "accept only numbers, one decimal point and exactly one number after the decimal.", the expression would look more like this:

```
/\d+\.\d/g
```

Can be read as "one or more digits, literal '.', one digit, look globally".