# Javascript validation for input type number

Tags: javascript

I have input type number to give the data of number of minutes. How can I validate this field to accept below scenario,

1. It should accept only positive numbers and min value is 0.5
2. It should accept values like 1.5, 0.5 but not values like 1.5.5, 12.5.6, -0.5

I have tried with below code but it is accepting multiple dots,

```
if ( (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31) && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
      }
```

Comment: Where's the code where you actually try to detect multiple dots? And what means *"to give the data of number of minutes"* ?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan  here is the code to detect multiple dots

`let df = questionDuration.toString();
      let length = df.replace(/[^.]/g, "").length;
      if(length >1){
        return false;
      }`

Comment: It'm still not sure (since you mentioned *minutes*) what are all the valid input values... :\

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan 

Input should accept values like 0.5,1 , 2.5


 Input should not accept values like 0, -1, -2.5

Comment: So are `99`, `9`, `9.9` valid? Or is `59` the max value?

Comment: Yes they are valid, no 59 is not the max value. There is no max validation

Comment: Is `4.8` valid ? Is `1000.9` valid?

Comment: Yes both are valid, if you have some solution please provide here

Comment: @Siva Kumar S When a a person will try to enter `0.5` first he will enter `0` which is invalid according to you.

Comment: @MaheerAli than, logically the validation should happen on `blur` or `submit` event, not on `input` event.

Comment: This is already answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609521/allowing-only-numbers-and-one-decimal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allowing only numbers and one decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609521/allowing-only-numbers-and-one-decimal)

Comment: Why don't you use `isNaN(input)` to check if `input` is a valid number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent user from entering more than 1 `.` and `-` using `e.preventDefault()` in keydown event.

```js
let input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('keydown',(e) => {
  if((e.key === '.' && e.target.value.includes('.')) || e.key === '-'){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Wrong Input")
  }
})
input.addEventListener('blur',(e) => {
   if(parseFloat(e.target.value) < 0.5) console.log("Input less than 0.5") 
})
```

```html
<input id="main" type="number" min="0.5"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a function to test the input value:

```js
function isInvalidInput (val) {
  return parseFloat(val) < 0.5 || isNaN(val);
}

console.log( isInvalidInput("-0.5") );   // true
console.log( isInvalidInput(-2) );       // true
console.log( isInvalidInput("1.2.5") );  // true
console.log( isInvalidInput("0.4") );    // true
console.log( isInvalidInput(0.4) );      // true
console.log( isInvalidInput("0.5") );    // false
console.log( isInvalidInput("1.2") );    // false
console.log( isInvalidInput("1000.9") ); // false
console.log( isInvalidInput(0.5) );      // false
console.log( isInvalidInput(0.999) );    // false
```

where `parseFloat(val) < 0.5` (if necessary parses the string and) makes sure it's greater than `0.5` - disallowing negative values, and `isNaN` parses the string and checks if the format is a `Number`.

If the function raises a`true` flag, the input is **invalid**.
If you want to invert the logic (like: `isValidInput`) than use `return !( /*logic here*/ );`

**Using [ES6 syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):**

```
const isInvalidInput = val => parseFloat(val) < 0.5 || isNaN(val);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `min` attribute value set to `0.5`, `RegExg` `/^\d+$|^\d+\.\d+$/` to match beginning of string one or more digits to end of string, or beginning of string one or more digit characters followed by dot character followed by one or more digit characters followed by end of string and check if `.value` is less than `min` attribute value at `blur` event handler,

```html
<input 
  type="number" 
  min="0.5"  
  onblur="if(!/^\d+$|^\d+\.\d+$/.test(this.value)||this.value<this.min)this.value=''">
```